# CSV file to FTP android

Tags: android, csv, ftp

here is m code for creating and uploading a csv file to ftp for acceleration data and time :

```js
case R.id.button_csv:
   start.setEnabled(true);
   pause.setEnabled(false);
   csv.setEnabled(false);
   
   try {
    String s;
    FileWriter datei = new FileWriter("Fahrt1.csv");
    BufferedWriter dateiFahrt = new BufferedWriter (datei);
    dateiFahrt.write("Time"+","+"ax"+","+"ay"+","+"az"+"\n");
    
    
    for (int i=0; i<sensorDataTime.size(); i++)
    {
     s=sensorDataTime.get(i)+","+sensorDataAx.get(i).toString()+","+sensorDataAy.get(i).toString()+","+sensorDataAz.get(i).toString()+"\n";
     dateiFahrt.write(s);
    }
    dateiFahrt.close();
    
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   
   
   goforIt(); //write to given ftp client
   
   break;
   
   
   
  }
 }   
 
//method for uploading a file to ftp client
public void goforIt(){


    FTPClient con = null;

    try
    {
        con = new FTPClient();
        con.connect("server");

        if (con.login("userName", "password"))
        {
            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String data = "Fahrt1.csv";

            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
            boolean result = con.storeFile("/Fahrt1.csv", in);
            in.close();
            if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
            con.logout();
            con.disconnect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
}
```

when i run my app on device evertyhin works fine but when i press the csv button then it throw me an excetption :

android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadExcetption. but eclipse says that my code is just fine. so what to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android like in most mobile environments it isn't permited to run network code on the `Main` thread since the main Thread is in charge of drawing UI and other taks relevant to the user experience, that's what that exception is telling you you'll need to use wrap the network code (tour `goForit()` in an `AsyncTask` or in a Thread